# Hide an <hr /> if it follows another <hr />, or if it is the last child, or both

Tags: css

I have a toolbar with various links, separated in groups with `<hr />` elements. Because which links are rendered depends on the user's permissions, we might end up with two consecutive separators, or with a separator at the end. This is what we don't want.

```
<a>Link 1</a>
<hr />
<!-- (not rendered) <a>Absent link 1</a> -->
<hr />
<a>Link 2</a>
<hr />
<!-- (not rendered) <a>Absent link 2</a> -->
```

These two issues are almost fixed with this CSS rule:

```
hr + hr, hr:last-child {
   display: none;
}
```

But in the following case, we have two `<hr />` at the end, and the rule above is not enough. After the second `<hr />` is hidden, the first one appears at the end visually, but is not the last element, so it isn't matched by the `:last-child` rule.

```
<a>Link 1</a>
<hr />
<!-- (not rendered) <a>Absent link 1</a> -->
<hr />
<!-- (not rendered) <a>Absent link 2</a> -->
```

How can I fix this with CSS only?

Comment: depending on your actual markup you could try to hide  `hr:nth-last-child(2)`

Comment: @fcalder Looks interesting, I didn't know about `:nth-last-child`. I think it will work if I always put an `<hr />` at the end (which will be always hidden).

Comment: Are the "not rendered" elements actually absent from the HTML source? Or are they present in the markup but hidden via css?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes they are absent from HTML (not even in comments as I represented them here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your links will be consistently using `<a>` elements, this will hide all `<hr />` sibling elements after the last link:

```
a:last-of-type ~ hr {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't think of using `:last-of-type`.
@fcalderan's suggestion would have worked too, I think, but in a slightly less elegant way, that would require always adding a final <hr> that is never displayed.
This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: If for some reason you had any `<hr />` elements before the first `<a>` element, you could add `hr:first-child` as another selector.

Comment: Sure, didn't encounter this case yet, but I will probably add it preventively.